# Work folders not working

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, network-share, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to configure work folders on W2012 R2.

I completed server configuration (as described in all procedures) and I have no error in server logs.

[image: server config]

Port 443 is in use by "windows sync share" service (if I stop this service the port is not in use anymore; so...)

I cannot use auto discovery because one of the domain controllers is still 2008R2, so I am configuring the clients using the direct url and this error is shown:

[image: client error]

On this server I have those roles installed:

- IIS (with one FTP site)
- WSUS with HTTP port 81 and HTTPS 8350)
- HyperV (not used, only as backup)
- WDS
- File server with DFSR

Comment: What happens when you go that URL with a browser?

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in Chrome, "This page can't be displayed" in IE

Answer (score 1):

ok! figured it out!

You have to create a certificate, also if all computers are connecting from the same domain (and they are trusted).

Just create a certificate (official authority or self-signed) and register it on server using command:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=<IP address>:443 certhash=<Cert thumbprint> appid={CE66697B-3AA0-49D1-BDBD-A25C8359FD5D} certstorename=MY
```

Then install it on clients in root certificate container.

I Also had to install GA update 2 on server.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Work Folder client requires an https connection. In your case no SSL certificate was specified.

To allow unsecure connections the following registry key (REG_DWORD) needs to be created on the client and set to one ('1'). This of course is not recommended for production environments.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WorkFolders\AllowUnsecureConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Windows Sync Share service starts up as System Account, that worked for me

Answer (score -1):

None of the above worked for me. The behaviour is repeated every time I do a server restart. I've created SSL certs for all involved machines and bound it to the default website in my domain. still every time I do a server restart Workfolders gives the message

"No Sync share could be found for the user"

..on every machine and nothing I do - short of completely removing the role, unencrypting all files and using a newly created certificate - fixes it.

Comment: So what is the real answer?